# Invariance of polynomial inequality over addition

Tags: calculus, inequality, polynomials

**Problem**:Let $r$ be a real number and $A$ be the set of polynomials of $\mathbb{R}$ which satisfy

1) $f(0) \geq 0$

2)if $f(0)=0$ then $f'(0)=0$ and $f"(0) \geq 0$

3) $f(0)f''(0)-(f'(0))^2 \geq rf(0)f'(0)$

Prove that if $f$ and $g$ are in $A$ then $f+g$ is also in $A$.

**My attempt**: I have dealt with the case in which either of $f$ or $g$ is $0$ at zero.

So, only left with the case $f(0)>0$ and $g(0)>0$  and also we can forget about the second condition.

I also observe that it is enough to prove that

$f(0)g''(0)+g(0)f''(0)-2f'(0)g'(0) \geq r(f(0)g'(0)+g(0)f'(0))$
holds given that $f(0)f''(0)-(f'(0))^2 \geq rf(0)f'(0)$ and analogously for $g$

I also observed that, $f(0)g''(0)+g(0)f''(0)-2f'(0)g'(0)=(g(x)f(-x))''$ at $x=0$.

but I cannot proceed furthur. Someone please help me.

Comment: @Macavity, sorry sir. I have edited it.